# gsl undefined symbol: gsl_multifit_nlinear_trs_lmaccel

Tags: c++, gsl

I'm having some troubles with the GNU Scientific Lbrary (GSL).
After having intalled it, I tested it with the example [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref.html#Using-the-library) and it works when compiling with:

```
gcc -Wall -c main.cpp ; gcc -L/usr/local/lib main.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -libtemt
```

Next, I tried to compile [that](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Geodesic-Acceleration-Example.html#Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Geodesic-Acceleration-Example) with no change in the source code nor the compiling command. But here is the problem, when I try to run the result, I get :

```
./a.out: symbol lookup error: ./a.out: undefined symbol: gsl_multifit nlinear_trs_lmaccel
```

I tried to comment it out, but it's making other issues. I found that variable in the fulle doc, but I can't find where it's defined.

As the first example is working, I think GSL was installed successfully, and as the same variableis used in different codes, I think it's a global variable, defined in th library.

Does anyone have an idea why I can't access it?

Thank's a lot!

Comment: did you install the dev packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of tears (no, it's a joke) I found a sort of answer:

I copy and paste libgsl.a and libgslcblas.a in my directory, i wrote that makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CXXFLAGS=-W -Wall -ansi -pedantic
LIBS=libgsl.a libgslcblas.a -lm
main:main.o
    $(CC) -o main main.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp 
    $(CC) -o main.o -c main.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)
```

I'm happy with that answer even if there is 2 weaknesses:
1) I don't know how to use shared library (at this moment)
2) I don't know how to make it by command line

Hope it will help someone